# Move elements to first position in nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, sorting

I want to move an element to first position from an inner array like below

```
{
 "activeContainerId": "955bd18f-6561-44b4-ba8f-7094e4e183b8",
  "amendCartContainers": [],
  "data": [
    {
        "id": "955bd18f-6561-44b4-ba8f-7094e4e183b8",
        "categoryName": "My_Category_Name",
        "categoryId": "cat_spc_my_category",
        "sections": [
            {
                "id": "cat_spc_my_id",
                "title": "APPLE",
                "items": [
                    {
                        "id": "a6d89ee2-6832-43e4-85ea-6ec541f06c36",
                        "action": "add",
                        "title": "Apple iPhone 11",
                        "characteristics": [
                            ----
                        ],
                        "promotions": [],
                        "quantity": 1,
                        "oneTimePrice": [
                            {
                                ----
                            }
                        ],
                        "recurringPrice": [],
                        "totalOneTimePrice": [
                            {
                                ----
                            }
                        ],
                        
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": "cat_spc_my_id2",
                "title": "My_Title2",
                "items": [
                    {
                        "id": "0ea7cade-96e0-4e5d-8baf-ace2f7ce123f",
                        "action": "add",
                        "title": "My Inner title2",
                        "characteristics": [],
                        "promotions": [],
                        "quantity": 1,
                        "addedBySCRuleEngine": true,
                        "oneTimePrice": [
                            {
                                ----
                            }
                        ],
                        "recurringPrice": [],
                        "totalOneTimePrice": [
                            {
                                ----
                            }
                        ],
                        "totalPriceRecurring": []
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": "cat_spc_my_special_id",
                "title": "my_special_title",
                "items": [
                    {
                        "id": "870d3871-6a0c-42f2-b123-9d75a3f3e3ee",
                        "action": "add",
                        "title": "my inner title3",
                        "characteristics": [],
                        "promotions": [
                            {
                                ----
                            }
                        ],
                        "quantity": 1,
                        "itemTerm": [
                            {
                                "duration": {
                                    "amount": 12,
                                    "units": "Month"
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "oneTimePrice": [
                            {
                                -----
                            }
                        ],
                        "recurringPrice": [
                            {
                                -----
                            }
                        ],
                        "totalOneTimePrice": [
                            {
                                -----
                            }
                        ],
                        "totalPriceRecurring": [
                            {
                                -----
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": "cat_spc_my_id4",
                "title": "my_title4",
                "items": [
                    {
                        "id": "1011730c-d8d2-45ac-8ee2-98f981184a85",
                        "action": "add",
                        "title": "my_title4",
                        "characteristics": [],
                        "promotions": [],
                        "quantity": 1,
                        "oneTimePrice": [
                            {
                                -----
                            }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "totalPriceOneTime": [
            {
                ----
            }
        ],
        "totalPriceRecurring": [
            {
                ----
            }
        ],
        "promotions": [],
        "notes": [],
        "processContext": "ACQ",
        "visibilityInSection": {
            "id": "bo_lov_visibilityinsection_section1",
            "name": "Section 1",
            "visibilityOrder": 1
        }
    }
],
"applyCouponStatus": null,
"promotions": [],
"totalPriceOneTime": [
    {
        "dutyFreeAmount": {
            "unit": "price_unit",
            "value": 479.68
        },
        "taxIncludedAmount": {
            "unit": "price_unit",
            "value": 580.41
        },
        "dutyFreeAlteredAmount": {
            "unit": "price_unit",
            "value": 479.68
        },
        "taxIncludedAlteredAmount": {
            "unit": "price_unit",
            "value": 580.41
        },
        "taxAmount": 100.73,
        "amountPayable": {
            "unit": "price_unit",
            "value": 580.41
        }
    }
],
"totalPriceRecurring": [
    {
        "dutyFreeAmount": {
            "unit": "price_unit",
            "value": 41.32
        },
        "taxIncludedAmount": {
            "unit": "price_unit",
            "value": 50
        },
        "dutyFreeAlteredAmount": {
            "unit": "price_unit",
            "value": 24.79
        },
        "taxIncludedAlteredAmount": {
            "unit": "price_unit",
            "value": 30
        },
        "taxAmount": 5.21,
        "amountPayable": {
            "unit": "price_unit",
            "value": 30
        }
    }
 ]
}
```

There are 4 items currently in the above array and I want to filter and move the id 'cat_spc_my_special_id' from '**data.sections** to the top of list. Keyword that I want to use is 'special' in this case.

I have tried below

**Try1:**

```
let filterKey = 'special';
const shoppingBagNew = shoppingBag?.data?. 
[0]?.sections.filter(function(x,y){
   return x == filterKey ? -1 : y == filterKey ? 1 : 0;
})
```

**Try2:**

```
const sections = shoppingBag?.data?.[0]?.sections;
const RedIndex = shoppingBag?.data?.[0]?.sections.findIndex(section => 
section.id == 'special');
 shoppingBag?.data?.[0]?.sections.push(...sections.splice(0, RedIndex));
 console.log('shoppingBag after filter',shoppingBag);
```

I knew that moving to the top of list is possible for only normal array of items which is not a nested array but Is this possible for a nested array like above? Any help would be appreciated..! Thanks.

Comment: so you want to re-order the contents of `.data[0].sections` array? what have you tried so far?

Comment: well, Try1: `filter` callback takes `item, index, array` as arguments, not sure how an Object could ever equal `special` .. Try2: no `section` object has a property called `name` ... so, not sure why you think `section.name` could equal `special` either

Comment: sorry its typo mistake, for Try2 I have to use either 'id' or 'title' but not 'name'.

Comment: sure, but neither of those will EQUAL `special` ... they may CONTAIN `special` though

Answer (score 0):

`.filter()` does not sort an array. You need to use `.sort()` instead:

```js
const shoppingBag={"activeContainerId":"955bd18f-6561-44b4-ba8f-7094e4e183b8","amendCartContainers":[],"data":[{"id":"955bd18f-6561-44b4-ba8f-7094e4e183b8","categoryName":"My_Category_Name","categoryId":"cat_spc_my_category","sections":[{"id":"cat_spc_my_id","title":"APPLE","items":[{"id":"a6d89ee2-6832-43e4-85ea-6ec541f06c36","action":"add","title":"Apple iPhone 11","characteristics":["something else"],"promotions":[],"quantity":1,"oneTimePrice":[{"something":"else"}],"recurringPrice":[],"totalOneTimePrice":[{"something":"else"}]}]},{"id":"cat_spc_my_id2","title":"My_Title2","items":[{"id":"0ea7cade-96e0-4e5d-8baf-ace2f7ce123f","action":"add","title":"My Inner title2","characteristics":[],"promotions":[],"quantity":1,"addedBySCRuleEngine":true,"oneTimePrice":[{"something":"else"}],"recurringPrice":[],"totalOneTimePrice":[{"something":"else"}],"totalPriceRecurring":[]}]},{"id":"cat_spc_my_special_id","title":"my_special_title","items":[{"id":"870d3871-6a0c-42f2-b123-9d75a3f3e3ee","action":"add","title":"my inner title3","characteristics":[],"promotions":[{"something":"else"}],"quantity":1,"itemTerm":[{"duration":{"amount":12,"units":"Month"}}],"oneTimePrice":[{"something":"else"}],"recurringPrice":[{"something":"else"}],"totalOneTimePrice":[{"something":"else"}],"totalPriceRecurring":[{"something":"else"}]}]},{"id":"cat_spc_my_id4","title":"my_title4","items":[{"id":"1011730c-d8d2-45ac-8ee2-98f981184a85","action":"add","title":"my_title4","characteristics":[],"promotions":[],"quantity":1,"oneTimePrice":[{"something":"else"}]}]}],"totalPriceOneTime":[{"something":"else"}],"totalPriceRecurring":[{"something":"else"}],"promotions":[],"notes":[],"processContext":"ACQ","visibilityInSection":{"id":"bo_lov_visibilityinsection_section1","name":"Section 1","visibilityOrder":1}}],"applyCouponStatus":null,"promotions":[],"totalPriceOneTime":[{"dutyFreeAmount":{"unit":"price_unit","value":479.68},"taxIncludedAmount":{"unit":"price_unit","value":580.41},"dutyFreeAlteredAmount":{"unit":"price_unit","value":479.68},"taxIncludedAlteredAmount":{"unit":"price_unit","value":580.41},"taxAmount":100.73,"amountPayable":{"unit":"price_unit","value":580.41}}],"totalPriceRecurring":[{"dutyFreeAmount":{"unit":"price_unit","value":41.32},"taxIncludedAmount":{"unit":"price_unit","value":50},"dutyFreeAlteredAmount":{"unit":"price_unit","value":24.79},"taxIncludedAlteredAmount":{"unit":"price_unit","value":30},"taxAmount":5.21,"amountPayable":{"unit":"price_unit","value":30}}]};

shoppingBag.data[0].sections.sort((a,b)=>
  a.id.includes("special")? -1 : b.id.includes("special") ? 1 : a.id.localeCompare(b.id)
);

// list ids of resulting array:
console.log(shoppingBag.data[0].sections.map(({id})=>id))
```

If you simply want to move the element containing "special" in its `id` to the top you should replace `a.id.localeCompare(b.id)` by `0` in the above `.sort()` function. This will keep the original order intact.

And, to answer your question concerning "nested" arrays: an array is an array is an array - no matter what type of elements are in it or whether it is nested or not. The `sort()` function works on the array "in place".

Btw, your "TRY 2" approach will also work (with a few little changes):

```js
const shoppingBag={"activeContainerId":"955bd18f-6561-44b4-ba8f-7094e4e183b8","amendCartContainers":[],"data":[{"id":"955bd18f-6561-44b4-ba8f-7094e4e183b8","categoryName":"My_Category_Name","categoryId":"cat_spc_my_category","sections":[{"id":"cat_spc_my_id","title":"APPLE","items":[{"id":"a6d89ee2-6832-43e4-85ea-6ec541f06c36","action":"add","title":"Apple iPhone 11","characteristics":["something else"],"promotions":[],"quantity":1,"oneTimePrice":[{"something":"else"}],"recurringPrice":[],"totalOneTimePrice":[{"something":"else"}]}]},{"id":"cat_spc_my_id2","title":"My_Title2","items":[{"id":"0ea7cade-96e0-4e5d-8baf-ace2f7ce123f","action":"add","title":"My Inner title2","characteristics":[],"promotions":[],"quantity":1,"addedBySCRuleEngine":true,"oneTimePrice":[{"something":"else"}],"recurringPrice":[],"totalOneTimePrice":[{"something":"else"}],"totalPriceRecurring":[]}]},{"id":"cat_spc_my_special_id","title":"my_special_title","items":[{"id":"870d3871-6a0c-42f2-b123-9d75a3f3e3ee","action":"add","title":"my inner title3","characteristics":[],"promotions":[{"something":"else"}],"quantity":1,"itemTerm":[{"duration":{"amount":12,"units":"Month"}}],"oneTimePrice":[{"something":"else"}],"recurringPrice":[{"something":"else"}],"totalOneTimePrice":[{"something":"else"}],"totalPriceRecurring":[{"something":"else"}]}]},{"id":"cat_spc_my_id4","title":"my_title4","items":[{"id":"1011730c-d8d2-45ac-8ee2-98f981184a85","action":"add","title":"my_title4","characteristics":[],"promotions":[],"quantity":1,"oneTimePrice":[{"something":"else"}]}]}],"totalPriceOneTime":[{"something":"else"}],"totalPriceRecurring":[{"something":"else"}],"promotions":[],"notes":[],"processContext":"ACQ","visibilityInSection":{"id":"bo_lov_visibilityinsection_section1","name":"Section 1","visibilityOrder":1}}],"applyCouponStatus":null,"promotions":[],"totalPriceOneTime":[{"dutyFreeAmount":{"unit":"price_unit","value":479.68},"taxIncludedAmount":{"unit":"price_unit","value":580.41},"dutyFreeAlteredAmount":{"unit":"price_unit","value":479.68},"taxIncludedAlteredAmount":{"unit":"price_unit","value":580.41},"taxAmount":100.73,"amountPayable":{"unit":"price_unit","value":580.41}}],"totalPriceRecurring":[{"dutyFreeAmount":{"unit":"price_unit","value":41.32},"taxIncludedAmount":{"unit":"price_unit","value":50},"dutyFreeAlteredAmount":{"unit":"price_unit","value":24.79},"taxIncludedAlteredAmount":{"unit":"price_unit","value":30},"taxAmount":5.21,"amountPayable":{"unit":"price_unit","value":30}}]};

// "TRY 2" of OP:
const sections = shoppingBag.data[0].sections,
      RedIndex = sections.findIndex(section => section.id.includes('special'));
 shoppingBag.data[0].sections.unshift(...sections.splice(RedIndex,1));
 
 // list ids of resulting array:
console.log(shoppingBag.data[0].sections.map(({id})=>id))
```

Instead of `.push()` which woud append an element to the end of an array you should use `.unshift()` which places it at the beginning of the array. And the `.splice()` should happen at the position where you found the "special" case:

```
shoppingBag.data[0].sections.unshift(...sections.splice(RedIndex,1));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have tried your solution but it's not working instead getting error as `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property '0' of object '[object Array]'`

Comment: You must have done something differently. The only assignment in my script is on line 1: `shoppingBag = ...`. Everything else happens without assigning any values to any properties. The sorting happens "in place". And, as you can see, the above snippet _does_ work.

Comment: I have used my 'Try2' solution as per your suggestions but getting error as `ShoppingCartContainer.tsx:699 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'sections')` I think it is not allowing to modify the existing `shoppingbag` array of objects. And 699 line of code is this one `const sections = shoppingBag.data[0].sections;`

Comment: The error shown indicates that the object under `shoppingBag.data[0]` seems to be `undefined` and therefore does not have a property named "sections". This is what "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'sections')" actually means. Can you maybe add the line `console.log(shoppingBag.data[0])` before line 699 to clarify this point?

Comment: Up until your latest comment  was unaware that your question concerns a *TypeScript* project. I have no experience with TypeScript and/or React. Maybe some further restrictions concerning the mutability of the object/array apply here?

Comment: Yes it is 'typescript' file only and React project only. I have kept `console.log(shoppingBag.data[0])` before 699 line and yes it is showing as `undefined` only

Comment: Well, in that case the data you are _actually_ dealing with has a different format from what you have shared in your post. You will need to find out more about your actual data.

Answer (score 0):

After so much effort I got a solution, I have used 'structuredClone' method it will do a deep copy of original object

```
const cloneShoppingBag = structuredClone(shoppingBag);
let sortCartSections = cloneShoppingBag?.data?.[0]?.sections;
if (sortCartSections) {
  sortCartSections.sort((a, b) =>
    a.title.includes("RED") && -1
  );
}
console.log('sortCartSections after sort',sortCartSections);
```